# Insert data in Linked List in java

Tags: java

Here is the Code I m using to insert elements in the Linked list but it stops till first element when try to fetch it. Anyone can you please help me in  this?

```
public void insert(int data) {   
    Node newnode = new Node(data);
    Node secound = null;
    Node Third;
    if(Head==null) {
        Head = newnode;
        Head.next=secound;
    }else{  
        secound = newnode;
        secound = secound.next;
    }   
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public void insert(int data)
{   
Node newnode= new Node(data);
if(Head==null)
{

    Head= newnode;
    Head.next=secound;
}

else
{

secound=newnode;
secound=secound.next;
}}
```

Comment: I dont understand how Node Head and secound is not Linked? Can anyone correct it.

Comment: In the `else` implementation, you're never storing `secound`...

Comment: What is this method supposed to do anyway?

Comment: I am inserting element in Linked-list, In that I m trying to link Head node and Secound Node, so that I can get elements while transversing Head Node.

Answer (score 0):

Here lies the problem with your code:

```
else
{   
secound=newnode;
secound=secound.next;
}
```

You shoud **link your currently added node to the last node in your list**. Currently your are creating a temporary `secound` object and it has no effect outside the scope of your function.

Comment: But I am linking secound  to Head Node in "If" code? Head has scope out of this function.

Comment: Yes, but head is your **first** node, you should link to **last**.

Comment: I see in my code secound goes to last node, and secound is linked to head. both are connected even though secound node expires after function ends right?Sorry Here may be my questions can be stupid I m kind f new in this.

Comment: I made secound as global scope problem still exists now?